# If $n$ is even, which values could $n \% 4$ be equal to?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am attempting to find a way to solve this problem. I understand that if $n$ is even, then $n = 2k$, however, I am struggling to understand how to solve this question.

I assume that since you are being asked $n \% 4$, that $2k$ will need to be divided by $4$ at some stage.

Could somebody explain to me the steps I would need to take to solve problems like this?

Comment: I hope $%$ means modulo or the remainder after division. Think how many remainders can you get when you divide any number by $4$? Under what conditions can you get those remainders?

Comment: Consider even and odd $k$.

Comment: If it's any comfort, I don't even know what kind of answer is expected. Which values  of $n$ are such that the remainder when divided by $4$ is $0$? Those that are equal to $4k$, for some whole number $k$. But this is just the definition of being divisible by $4$. I really do not get this question.

Comment: Just start out by trying numbers and see if you see an obvious pattern. If $n=0$ then remainder $0$. If $n = 2$ then remainder is $2$. If $n = 4$ then remainder is $0$. If $n = 6$ then remainder is $2$. If $n = 8$ then remainder is $0$. Do you see a pattern? If yes, try and prove it.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to start from the other end.

$n \mod 4$ can be $0,1,2$ or $3$.

If $n \mod 4 = 0$ then $n=4k$ for some integer $k$. Is $n$ even or odd ?

If $n \mod 4 = 1$ then $n=4k+1$ for some integer $k$. Is $n$ even or odd ?

If $n \mod 4 = 2$ then $n=4k+2$ for some integer $k$. Is $n$ even or odd ?

If $n \mod 4 = 3$ then $n=4k+3$ for some integer $k$. Is $n$ even or odd ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The values of $n\bmod4$ are in $[0,3]$ periodically, and it suffices to try with $n=0$ and $n=2$.

Comment: Note that the hint is about $100\%$ of the answer.